# Separating string from white space from a vector

Tags: java, string, loops, vector, jtextarea

So essentially I have an object of vectors and in a specific instance called 'comments' I have comments that actually have String in them and some that are just white space or have a single space.  I tried to separate these from each other and I am running into trouble.  Everything is outputted for some strange reason.  Any thoughts? (display is a JTextArea)

```
     for (int x = 0; x<dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.size(); x++)    
     {

        if(dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.elementAt(x).getComment() == "//s" || dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.elementAt(x).getComment() == null){
            System.out.println("Blank");

        }
        else{                           
            display.append("Name: " + dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.elementAt(x).getFName() + " " + dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.elementAt(x).getLName() + newLine);
            display.append("Comment: " + dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.elementAt(x).getComment() + newLine);
            display.append("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + newLine);
        }
    } // end first for loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by `\\s` it's since you're not using regular expressions there. The following check should work:

```
String comment = dogParkProgramMain.infoVector.elementAt(x).getComment();

if (comment == null || comment.trim().isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("Blank");
}
```

`trim()` function will remove all leading and trailing spaces from the string meaning that if your string only contains spaces it would end up empty after `trim`. This code will check for any number of spaces as opposed to only one space mentioned in your question.